# How to properly format an IEEE table with multiple headers and across two columns paper

Tags: tables, ieeetran

Hello I am using `Overleaf` for writing a paper for IEEE and I am having a bit of difficulties formatting a table.

Below **the incorrect** table I have so far:

[image]

And below **the correct** table I am trying to achieve. Notice that it extend across the two columns and between the header "Top 10 journals - PM-SSCM" and the header "Top 10 journals - DST-SSCM" there is a break that I am also trying to achieve.

[image]

Below the script I have so far:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{seqsplit, collcell, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash\collectcell\seqsplit}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\usepackage{lipsum}

// some paragraphs....

\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L{0.8}L{1.1}L{1.1} @{}}
    \toprule
Top ten journals related to QUERY-1 \\
    \midrule
Journal Title    &   Publication \\
    &   Journal of cleaner Production
        &   40 \\
    &   International Journal of Production Economics
        &   28 \\
    &   International Journal of Production Research
        &   23 \\
    &   Supply Chain Management an International Journal
        &   20 \\
    &   Business Strategy and the Environment
        &   40 \\
    &   International Journal of Operations Production Management
        &   28 \\
    &   International Journal of Production Research
        &   23 \\
    &   Supply Chain Management an International Journal
        &   20 \\
    \bottomrule
    \toprule
Top ten journals related to QUERY-1 \\
    \midrule
Journal Title    &   Publication \\
    &   Journal of cleaner Production
        &   40 \\
    &   International Journal of Production Economics
        &   28 \\
    &   International Journal of Production Research
        &   23 \\
    &   Supply Chain Management an International Journal
        &   20 \\
    &   Business Strategy and the Environment
        &   40 \\
    &   International Journal of Operations Production Management
        &   28 \\
    &   International Journal of Production Research
        &   23 \\
    &   Supply Chain Management an International Journal
        &   20 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
```

I studied the [following table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525522/formatting-a-table-with-multiple-headers-like-this) which was helpful for understanding the concept of multi-headers.

I have used the [following source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314621/table-with-multiple-header-column-span-and-footer-total-line) in order to achieve the type of table I wanted and that was useful but I have some formatting problems as shown in the picture. Also I understand this is not totally related to the example I am trying to achieve but it was useful to understand the main idea/concept.

Also came across [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246416/how-to-set-bold-small-caps-in-a-table-header) which was also useful but not enough for me to be able to properly solve the problem.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction to find a solution.

Comment: How do you define the `L` column type?

Comment: Hello @Bernard and thanks for reading the question. I defined `L` from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602275/fit-table-into-one-column-for-ieee-has-formatting-problem)

Comment: The problem is that I never built a multi-header table and because of that I am not entirely sure about the proper definition of `L`. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398081/formatting-a-table-with-multiple-headers-using-tabular-like-this) was useful too but it confused me because of the empty  space in the double-header.

Comment: I don't understand why each of your tables have 3 columns, but you seem to need only 2 really.

Comment: That is what I thought too but that also does not work. If I change the statement from `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L{0.8}L{1.1}L{1.1} @{}}` to `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L{1.1}L{1.1} @{}}` [this](https://i.imgur.com/HTAxuz6.png) is the result. As you see nothing really changes. So I am not really sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution, with `X` and `c` columns:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,blindtext}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}%
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{seqsplit, collcell, ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\arraybackslash\collectcell\seqsplit}X<{\endcollectcell}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}%
                     \hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X c !{\qquad}Xc}
    \toprule
    Top ten journals related to QUERY-1 & & Top ten journals related to QUERY-1 \\
    \cmidrule(r{1.8em}){1-2} \cmidrule{3-4}
    Journal Title & Publication & Journal Title & Publication \\
    \midrule
     Journal of cleaner Production & 40 & Journal of cleaner Production & 40 \\
     International Journal of Production Economics & 28 & International Journal of Production Economics & 28 \\
     International Journal of Production Research & 23 & International Journal of Production Research & 23 \\
     Supply Chain Management an International Journal & 20 & Supply Chain Management an International Journal & 20 \\
     Business Strategy and the Environment & 40 & Business Strategy and the Environment & 40 \\
     International Journal of Operations Production Management & 28 & International Journal of Operations Production Management & 28 \\
     International Journal of Production Research & 23 & International Journal of Production Research & 23 \\
     Supply Chain Management an International Journal & 20 & Supply Chain Management an International Journal & 20 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your time in helping me out to find a solution! It works!

Comment: Hello Bernard, I wanted to ask you, if you have a little bit of time to spare, to check a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603022/ieee-table-with-multiple-headers-and-three-columns-layout) I just posted. Thanks if you can!